# this + class selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I'm currently using LESS instead of CSS and I would like to know if there is a way to get the current selector + a class. There is a way of doing this with a pseudo-class but as far as I'm aware, not with a class.

Psuedo-Class:

```
li {
    a {
        &:hover {

        }
    }
}
```

The `&:hover` basically gets `li a:hover`. What I would like to know is how I would do this for a class. For example, if I wanted to get `ul li.active` I'd have to use the below:

```
ul {
    li {

    }
    li.active {

    }
}
```

I was hoping for something closer to the first segment of code but I couldn't see anything on the [LESS features page](http://lesscss.org/features/). Is there something like this that I just overlooked?

Comment: have not used LESS but I guess it may be `& + a { ... }`

Comment: Looks like I guess correctly, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/

Comment: @KingKing I think you may have been confused as this wasn't what I was asking. BoltClock's answer is correct.

Comment: yes, I was confused by this statement ***I would like to know if there is a way to get the current selector + a class***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain the class selector like you would with a pseudo-class:

```
ul {
    li {
        &.active {

        }
    }
}
```

You can do this with any one or more simple selectors that isn't a type or `*` selector, as well as with a pseudo-element. The `&` can occur in most places where a selector fragment can be injected into another without causing a syntax error; the examples given in the documentation with pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements are not the only ones. The documentation has an entire section on using `&` which can be found [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature).

Comment: Thanks! The online converter I was using didn't support this I guess so I was avoiding it in my actual code. Thanks though, it works.